# how to use Views Datasource to export view in JSON

Tags: views

I am new in Drupal. I am using Drupal 7 and i have created a view based on the terms and displaying it as Block to display it in the website. But, I want to export the view data in the JSON format.

I have installed Views Datasource module and enabled it in the Module administration.

But, i can't see the way to export my current view data to JSON through this module.

Can any one please help? is there any settings i am missing?

or is there any easy way like modules or plugins i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by combination of two modules. [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) and [Views data export - JSON support](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export_json). Once you install these two modules create a view as data export and select format as JSON.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

Comment: Hi, I have installed both modules but how to make it work? what i have to do to export my view to json?

Comment: You're trying to export view data right? I have updated my answer above to include screenshot. I don't have JSON support installed but it should be same as setting up CSV option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can now display the data in JSON. Just one quick question. I am loading values from 2 terms and i want o create different arrays in the JSON file for example:
{
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": [
            {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4}
        ],
        "Ford": [
            {"model":"Taurus", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Escort", "doors":4}
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: But right now, i am getting this result
[      {"no name":"<a href=\"\/color-management\/red\">Red<\/a>"}  ,    {"no name":"<a href=\"\/color-management\/white\">white<\/a>"}]

Answer (score 0):

To use [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) to output JSON:

1. Enable the views datasource sub-module views_json
2. Add a new Page display to your view
3. Under "Format" switch to "JSON data document"
4. Set the path for your display

[image: views datasource json]